# django_filter ModelChoiceFilter auth.models.User ForeignKey to_field_name

Tags: django, django-users, django-filter

I am using django_filter to apply filtering to django_tables2 rendered in my template (Django 1.11). One of the fields I would like to filter on is a ForeignKey from in-built User model:

```
class User(auth.models.User,auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

class Task(models.Model):
    assigned = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

My filter is setup as follows:

```
class TaskFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    assigned = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=User.objects.filter(is_staff=False),label=('Assigned'))
```

The filtering works fine but rather than the default "username" being displayed in the filter dropdown I would like to use the full name of the user: `get_full_name`

Does anyone have advice on how to acheive this? Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: How do you render this choices?

Comment: {% bootstrap_form filter.form layout='inline' %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I worked out a solution to this. Not sure if this is the correct way to do or just a work around but in any event it is working fine for me.

Changed the filter type to ChoiceField:

```
assigned = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=get_full_names,label=('Assigned'))
```

And populated the CHOICES using the following:

```
def get_full_names():
    full_names = ()
    users = User.objects.filter(is_staff=False)
    for user in users:
        full_names += (user.id, user.get_full_name),
    return full_names
```

Hopefully this helps someone else who has the same problem.