# Filtering by nested foreignkey field with django-filters

Tags: python, django

I've a Customer model which has User as a foreignkey field. In Customer ListView I want to search by name of Customer (Customer --> User --> Name). The ModelChoiceFilter is giving s list of all user objects as a dropdown. I'm unable to figure out how can I put it as a search box of names.

Based on [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49103743/django-filter-modelchoicefilter-auth-models-user-foreignkey-to-field-name), I tried to put it as a ChoiceFilter with a callable as choices argument, but then pagination object started giving error. Could anyone please help.

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Filters.py

```
class CustomerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    User = get_user_model()
    user = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=User.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = {
            'user':[],
        }
```